# How can I implement dynamic Layered ImageView Programmatically?

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-custom-view, layered

I want to have **layered images** as attached below.

Currently, I am doing it like this

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


      <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I feel this manual method using XML may vary and react based on different **devices and screen** types. So, How can I achieve it in the better or best way? How can I make it dynamic?

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to implement the **layered imageview programatically**. However, this does not feel the best solution.
Hope, it will help others as well.

```
class ThumbView extends RelativeLayout {
    private ImageView vLayer1;
    private ImageView vLayer2;
    private ImageView vLayer3;

    public ThumbView(Context context, String pathToFile) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_thumb, this, true);
        vLayer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        vLayer2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view2);
        vLayer3 = view.findViewById(R.id.view3);

        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(pathToFile);

        vLayer1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        vLayer2.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        vLayer3.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```